# How adjust the vertical space in aligned equations (in the Preamble)?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I always find the standard `\\` to be too little in aligned equations. I used to do `\\[5mm]` or similar in the past, but there must be some automatic way to do this once and for all in the preamble. Is there?

Comment: `\openup 1\jot`, perhaps.

Comment: I'll try it out in a sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved my problem here was actually writing `\setlength{\jot}{<length>}` in the preamble. Other alternatives, such as `\openup 1\jot` was OK except for the fact that it also stretched some other spacing e.g. the spacing between the lines in the table of content.