# amsmath & task environment improve spacing between fractions inside radicals

Tags: amsmath, line-spacing, tasks

The vertical line spacing problem. The solution steps shown below are IMHO too tight because the fractions are inside a radical.

I tried a couple of hacks to increase the vertical line spacing within each item. No success.

Your assistance is most appreciated (especially by students).

[image]

````
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%\usepackage{bm}%bold equation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algegra II: Assignment: 9-E}
       {}
       {Due 02/24/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Find all solutions (real and imaginary/complex roots) to each quadratic equation. Simplify answers.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
  
\begin{document}
\pagetop

\settasks{
    after-item-skip=3em,    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=2em,
    item-indent=3em,
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=2em
}
\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&3x^2+27=0 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&3x^2=-27 \\
&x^2= -9 \\   &\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{-9}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{9}\\
&x=\pm3i
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)
%Problem #2
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&x^2=-12 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{-12} \\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{12}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}\\
&x=\pm2i\sqrt{3}
\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
%Problem #3
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&-9x^2=16 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\dfrac{-9x^2}{-9}=\dfrac{16}{-9} \\
&x^2=\dfrac{-16}{9}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{-16}{9}}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{-16}}{\sqrt{9}}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=\pm \dfrac{i\sqrt{16}}{3}\\
&x=\pm \dfrac{4i}{3}\\
\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
%Problem 4
        \task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&4x^2+48=0 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{-12} \\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{12}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}\\
&x=\pm2i\sqrt{3}
\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
%Problem 5
        \task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&5x^2=-81 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\dfrac{5x^2}{5}=\dfrac{-81}{5} \\
&x^2=\dfrac{-81}{5}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{-81}{5}}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{-81}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=\pm \dfrac{i\sqrt{81}}{\sqrt5}\\
&x=\pm \dfrac{9i\sqrt{5}}{5}\\
\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
\end{tasks}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Please supply an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`} that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to solve it. To me the typeset result you show looks fine. BTW `\hspace` produces horizontal spacing while `\vspace` is for vertical spacing. Shouldn't you be trying `\vspace`?

Comment: @PeterWilson  very sorry. I forgot to hit "enter" to separate the ``` from the first line of code. For some reason, when I separated the opening ``` from ```\documentclass[12pt]{exam}``` the 1st line of code was no longer hidden. Thanks for calling out that error!

Comment: With this post perhaps  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174819/how-adjust-the-vertical-space-in-aligned-equations-in-the-preamble

Answer (score 1):

Please supply an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it.

To me the typeset result you show looks fine.

BTW `\hspace` produces horizontal spacing while `\vspace` is for vertical spacing. Shouldn't you be using `\vspace` not `\hspace`?

Comment: Mr. Wilson, that ```\hspace``` was suggested by another tex.stack-er. However, **within each individual task** I replaced all the ```\hspace``` with ```\vspace``` and no difference when complied. No idea why.  Can I possibly share an image comparing the 2 options with you? Also, any way in increase the vertical line spacing by a few "em"

Comment: @pascal974     Thanks very much for your suggestion. ```\setlength{\jot}{1em}```  in the preamble did the trick. Never would have found that  solution but for you!

Comment: @Math, glad you have an answer.  Peter W.